# How to order a list of ip addresses

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort the following list in order:

```
the_list = ["192.168.0.1",
        "192.168.0.15", 
        "192.168.0.2", 
        "192.168.0.10", 
        "192.168.0.11",
        "192.168.0.24", 
        "192.168.0.8"
    ]
```

This results in:

```
print(sorted(the_list))
[
    '192.168.0.1', 
    '192.168.0.10', 
    '192.168.0.11', 
    '192.168.0.15', 
    '192.168.0.2', 
    '192.168.0.24', 
    '192.168.0.8'
]
```

But I want it to be ordered like so:

```
[
    '192.168.0.1', 
    '192.168.0.2', 
    '192.168.0.10', 
    '192.168.0.11', 
    '192.168.0.15', 
    '192.168.0.24', 
    '192.168.0.8'
]
```

So basically it's ordered by the number after the final point, so instead of .1, .10, .15, .2; it will be .1, .2, .10, .15

Comment: Title tells a different story.

Comment: This is a list, not dictionary.

Comment: Why is `'192.168.0.8'` last?

Answer (score 1):

If all your IPs start with `192.168.0.`:
You can use this lambda function:

```
the_list = ["192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.15", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.10", "192.168.0.11","192.168.0.24", "192.168.0.8"]
the_list= sorted(the_list, key=lambda x:int( x.split('.')[-1]))
```

Otherwise, taking into account that IPs have this structure xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:

```
the_list = ["193.168.0.1", "192.168.0.15", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.10", "192.169.0.11","191.168.0.24", "192.168.0.8"]
the_list = sorted(the_list, key=lambda x:"".join([i.zfill(3) for i in x.split('.')]))
```

Comment: this will work only of all address start with `192.168.0`

Comment: @ElegantOdoo I think that was the case of the user, however, I've added also the general case. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Python has batteries for this use case too!

```
import ipaddress

print(sorted(the_list, key=ipaddress.IPv4Address))
```

`ipaddress` already knows how to compare IP addresses correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> def sort_key(key):
...     return int(key.split(".")[-1])
...
>>> sorted(the_list, key=sort_key)
['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2', '192.168.0.8', '192.168.0.10', '192.168.0.11', '192.168.0.15', '192.168.0.24']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the more general case when the i.p's differ in several locations -

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def sort_func(x, y):
    s_x = [int(z) for z in x.split(".")]
    s_y = [int(z) for z in y.split(".")]
    for i, j in zip(s_x, s_y):
        if i < j: return -1
        if j < i: return 1
    return 0

sorted(the_list, key = cmp_to_key(sort_func))
```